# How to validate the content of a Text widget while this Text widget loses focus?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

There is a command `validatecommand` in `Entry` widget. But there is not a simulated command in `Text` widget.

How to implement the function in Text widget in tkinter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate the data when the widget loses focus, you would simply bind a function to the `<FocusOut>` event.